# Trying to sanitize user input to dynamically set column name in PearDB prepared statement

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement, pear

I'm trying to write a simple method to sort some DB results. We are stuck using PEAR DB, which is an old OO data object class.

I need to dynamically set which column we sort by:

```
$query = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM ' . $this->table . ' WHERE ? IS NOT NULL');
```

The problem occurs because when the statement is executed, I wind up with the column name in regular quotes instead of slanted ones, so in the example, the column is never NULL.

Comment: bounce it against a list of known good column names... `in_array`

Comment: You mean "table name", not "column name", right?

Comment: Do you then have a bind statement?

Comment: No, I actually mean column name.  This example is in a generic DAO class, and all our data classes extend it.  $this->table is a property of whatever child class we are in, and is set to the table corresponding to a given class.

Thanks, Orangepill.  That just might work, especially since each class already has an array of the columns as a property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this, it will bump the requested column up against a list of known good column.

```
 $columns = array("id", "name", "zipcode");
 if (!in_array($requestedCol, $columns)){
     // either reset $requestedCol to a default or error
 }
 $query = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM ' . $this->table . ' WHERE '.$requestedColumn.' IS NOT NULL');
```

Comment: You are 100% correct.  See my comment above.  In addition to a $table property, each data class already has a $columns property so this is a perfect 5 second solution for me.